# Linq to SQL on EF 6 - create range 1 to n and do a join on it

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Trying to rewrite some old stored procedures to EF queries. We have one where part of it checks the availability of all positions for a location by generating an int range with a table-valued function, then returning all the unused ones, like so:

```
select lp.value
from ( 
   select x.value
   from Location l 
   cross apply dbo.intRange(1, l.Positions) x
) lp
left join Action j on lp.value = j.Position
where j.id is null
```

Is there a way to do that with Linq to SQL? I'm guessing no, given that the only way to do it originally was to define a function, but I figured I should check first.

Comment: What is the range of `l.Positions`? If I understand this correctly, it seems like a really hard way to generate `dbo.intRange(1, MAX(l.Positions))`?

Comment: Also, which LINQ: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x and what database provider?